# How to write the pattern attribute of an input telephone number in HTML?

Tags: html, web, input, attributes

The question is as :

- The Telephone input field type should be 'tel',
- The placeholder text should be `Pattern: 234-567-8910`
- The pattern to restrict the entry and it should be a mandatory (`required`) field
- Pattern should be of the type `[ Pattern:  234-567-8910]`.
- Element name should be: `telephone`.

My code is

`<input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" required placeholder="Pattern: 234-567-8910" pattern="">`

What to write in the attribute pattern ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the question please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern in an input would take a regular expression. Your requirement is to get a regex what would fit in the requirement  [ Pattern: 234-567-8910].

The regex would be

```
 pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you do not understand, pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}", its like you are telling that the user can enter 3 digits from 0-9, than again 3 digits [0-9], than finally 4 digits between 0-9.

But the question is, why can't we write [0-9]{10}??

Comment: You can write [0-9]{10}, but it depends upon tel-number pattern